# Visual-Studio, Database save error "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 13,Token in error = , ]"

Tags: visual-studio

OK so I recently started getting into programming simple programs and I have taught myself everything using guides on the internet thus far and I have been doing really well and things have been working great, until now. So i feel that I have done a lot, A LOT of searching on this question and I cant seem to find an answer or even anyone else out there that is having the same problem as me. Im going to try to make this as simple as possible so here it goes.

I have made a program in visual studio that is simply supposed to allow me to make entries in fields such as first name, last name, and so on. It works like a charm and saves data like normal, I can close out and re open it and the data is there. **BUT**

While messing with the program and trying to test it I found that if I **DELETED** a row of data that i had previously inserted then added **ANY** new data then clicked the **SAVE** button it would crash every single time.

First it would say there is no proper delete command. So i gave it one, and it stopped giving me that error message. Then it said it was the update command. So i gave it one then that stopped showing up. But now it gives me the error message. "**There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 13,Token in error = , ]**. And it gives me this error every time i try to save after following the above steps. And I honestly dont know what to make of it.

I know im going to need to post a sample of my code that I have but I dont know what part of it to post so I figured I would wait and see so I dont post 1,500+ lines on here.

This is the only thing preventing my program from working correctly and if I wouldnt ask if I wasnt completely stumped. And im roughly 300% stumped. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a small but *complete* code sample?

Comment: I believe so. For the sake of saving some time I want to make sure I pull it from the correct  spot. When I get the error message after the crash it takes me to the same point in the code each time with an arrow on a certain line stating that this will be the next line executed. Are you wanting the code around that area? Sorry like I said im new and im not sure which code to post.

Comment: I cant figure out exactly where the error is occuring it wont reference me to a line where the error is. Unless i just dont know how to interpret the token error message. I have done more searching and it seems to be that a comma is in the wrong place or there is a space where there shouldnt be. But visual studio has basically done all the coding for me so i dont know how that would have happened.